# Event and Goal, Click on e-mail button

Tags: wordpress, events, google-analytics

I would like to know how many visitors clicked on a specific e-mail button. I have added the following to the button link:

[button size="large" link="mailto:mailadress" button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'name button', 'mailto:mailadress'] Text[/button]

And in my analytics panel I go to Admin>>Goals>>New Goal>> give it a name and chose Event option and then added category: button, action: click, and Saved.

It is still not working. Is something wrong with my code? It is a WordPress website. Do I need to add anything extra?

Comment: Is this a wordpress shortcode ? In any case you are missing a closing bracket in the send-call and the last parameter for an event is supposed to be a positive integer (or 0).

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a syntax error with your button. The onclick event and ga function is not closed. It should look like this:

```
[button size="large" link="mailto:mailadress" button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'name button', 'mailto:mailadress')"] Text[/button]
```

As Eike Pierstorff mentioned, it looks like you're using a shortcode to output the button. If the shortcode does not support an onclick attribute, it will not print it in the final HTML code even if you fix the syntax.

You can check the output in Chrome by right-clicking on the link on your site (the front-end, not the admin area) and clicking Inspect Element. If you don't see the onclick attribute in the HTML code, the shortcode is not printing it.

You can check if your shortcode supports a class or id attribute, then use that attribute as a selector in your own Javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if ( typeof( ga ) != 'undefined' ) {
        $('#your-id').on('click', function() {
            ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'name button', 'mailto:mailadress');
        });
    }
}
```

To implement this, you'll need to know how to write and enqueue JavaScript.